# How to solve SSRS timeout problem for heavy reports

Tags: reporting-services

I did my best to create huge report for someone who still likes to work with  200K rows Excel file rather then to get some useful summary. Report is pretty simple SQL-wise but because of load and probably rendering time it time out on the server. I don't have any option to change time out value on server.

What is good way to solve this task:  i.e. to create  40mB Excel for user via subscription or posting.
All SQL performance attempts  already exhausted. Should I move to SSIS which I think can handle such task.
I'm on SSRS 2016
[image]

Thanks
Mario

Comment: Lots of options to do this kind of thing. I would look at SSIS or even Excel Power Query to embed the query into Excel. The user can just hit refresh when they want the latest data .

Comment: Thanks Alan, I will check PQ. My data on the SQL Server.